# How to pass SQLite query results to another page for ListView in Flutter

Tags: sqlite, flutter, listview

How can I show below queryRow() list to another page as ListView? How can I transfer data from below page to another as queryRow[]. Please kindly support me for the solution since I am sick and tired of to search and try. :)

```
   List<Map<String, dynamic>> queryRow;

   @override
   void initState() {
   super.initState();

   queryRow = []; // initialization
   }

  

   FlatButton(
   onPressed: () async {
   final data = await DatabaseHelper.instance.queryAll();
   setState(() {
     queryRow = data;
    });
   },
   child: Text('Query'),
    ),
```

Comment: What have you tried? Stack Overflow expects you to have done some research before asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

There's a load of options to do this. Check out [this overview](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options).